# Writing expression syntax for Calculate Field in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3

I'm stuck on my CalculateField function with how to correctly type the syntax.

I'm not particularly tied to the variables I assigned up front.

The issue is syntax for the expression.

I am currently using ArcGIS 10.3 and Python 2.7.8.

This is the line that is getting me:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "Cohort", expression="""openYear + " to " + closeYear""")
```

How should I be writing the expression?

```
expression="'str(openYear)' + " to " + 'str(closeYear)'"
```

The rest is a sample of my loop statement.

```
#################################
for fc in fcList:
    openYear=fc[12:16]
    closeYear=fc[20:24]
    # Add "Cohort" field to *USA feature classes in scratch.mdb
    print fc
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "Cohort", "TEXT")
    print "Cohort added."
    # Calculate "Cohort" field to match feature class name in scratch.mdb  
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "Cohort", expression="""openYear + " to " + closeYear""")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the calculate field arcpy function requires the proper string input as its expression. You need to create a string that looks exactly like it would in ArcGIS's field calculator. For text fields, this means your text surrounded by double quotation marks. Something like this:

`"1945 to 1965"`

Translating that into a python string isn't too tough. If you want double quotes in your strings, open and close your string with single quotes.

`'"1945 to 1965"'`

Now to substitute the years with the variable values:

`'"' + openYear + " to " + closeYear + '"'`

or:

`'"{0} to {1}"'.format (openYear, closeYear)`

The final code:

`CalculateField_management (fc, "Cohort", '"{0} to {1}"'.format (openYear, closeYear))`