# ArcPy expression syntax in CalculateField_management

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.7

I am trying create a new column in my shapefile by concatenating a fixed/defined value with the value in another column. I have a syntax error that I can't seem to catch. Below is my code, current output, and desired output. There is a similar question at [Writing expression syntax for Calculate Field in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164440), but my case is a little different.

I am using ArcMap 10.7 & Python 2.7.

```
myval = 1
arcpy.AddField_management(myshp, "newCol", "TEXT")
expression = str(myval) + '-0' + str("!otherCol!")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(myshp, "newCol", expression, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

**Current Output**

| otherCol | newCol |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | -1 |
| 2 | -1 |
| 2 | -1 |
| 1 | 0 |

**Desired Output**

| otherCol | newCol |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1-02 |
| 2 | 1-02 |
| 2 | 1-02 |
| 1 | 1-01 |

I also tried `expression = str(myval) + '-0' + str(int("!otherCol!"))`, but it threw the following error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '!feat_ds_id!'`.

The field `otherCol` is type Double.

---

This syntax is closer, but still not quite there:

```
expression = '"' + str(myval) + '-0' + '!otherCol!' + '"'
```

| otherCol | newCol |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1-02.0 |
| 2 | 1-02.0 |
| 2 | 1-02.0 |
| 1 | 1-01.0 |

Comment: The general advice in that other answer is still valid-- if you print `expression` it should be something valid that you could paste into the Field Calculator window in ArcMap.  It might be easiest to build it there first, get it working, then translate that to work within your Python script

Comment: This Question really doesn't have a problem specific to GIS; this just an exercise in formatting strings with Python. I suggest you learn how to use the `str.format()` function, since doing string math is wasteful of resources and prone to error.

Comment: @Vince Using `expression = '"' + "{}-0{}".format(myval, '!otherCol!') + '"'` returns as shown in the last table in the OP. Using `expression = '"' + "{}-0{:.0f}".format(myval, '!otherCol!') + '"'` returns `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'` although `otherCol` is definitely a Double. Surely would appreciate advice on this.

Comment: Don't mix typed and untyped formats; you only need one `format` (without the string math).

Comment: @Vince how is `expression = '"{}-0{}"'.format(myval, '!otherCol!')` mixing?

Comment: The example with `"{}-0{:.0f}"` generated the error.

Answer (score 2):

To do this I would use two Python string methods (`format` and `zfill`).

I find workflows like this much easier when approached using `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()` rather than the `CalculateField_management()` function because the syntax of the latter is less intuitive to me.

I tested this code using ArcMap 10.8:

```
myval = 1
arcpy.AddField_management(myshp, "newCol", "TEXT")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(myshp,["newCol","otherCol"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = "{0}-{1}".format(myval,str(int(row[1])).zfill(2))
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

and got the result your question is looking for:

[image]